# SQL query for selecting foreign-key rows with more than one link to the primary-key table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a (simplified) scenario that goes something like this:

**Document table**:

```
   id   |    title   |  text
   ===========================
    1   |    Title1  |  "AAA"
    2   |    Title2  |  "BBB" 
    3   |    Title3  |  "CCC"
```

**Document pictures**

```
   id   |   doc_id    |  url
   ===================================================
    1   |    1       |  "http://some.domain.com/1.jpg"
    2   |    1       |  "http://some.domain.com/2.jpg"
    3   |    2       |  "http://some.domain.com/3.jpg"
    4   |    4       |  "http://some.domain.com/3.jpg"
```

Let's name these table `documents` and `doc_pictures`. I'm trying to create a query that will return all the documents that have more than one picture. In this example this means returning only the document with id `1`.

**Limitations and assumptions**:

1. Both of the tables are huge thus complex queries might take too long.
2. I don't care how many foreign picture rows the document has. I only care that it's more than 1.
3. I don't mind if the output is the id of the document or the row from the pictures table.
4. **I don't mind getting just a small subset of such documents (for example 10 documents that have more than 1 picture, and not all of the documents that have more than 1 picture)**

**The db is Mysql**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be used to get the document ids.

```
 select 
     doc_id,
     count(1)
 from 
     doc_pictures
 group by 
     doc_id
 having 
     count(1) > 1
```

And then you can use a `where in` on the `documents` table using those ids.

Something like this:

```
 select 
     *
 from
     documents
 where 
     id in (
        select 
            doc_id                
        from 
            doc_pictures
        group by 
            doc_id
        having 
            count(1) > 1
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select doc_id
from doc_pictures
group by doc_id
having count(distinct url) > 1;
```

Comment: What was the problem??

Comment: It did not return the correct results.  The voted answer, above, did.